# Version of WebKit in JavaFX 8 WebView

Tags: webkit, javafx-8

What is the version of WebKit in JavaFX 8?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can determine the base version of WebKit being used in WebView by [querying the user agent string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getUserAgent--) of the WebView's engine.

```
web.getEngine().getUserAgent()
```

This shows a WebKit version of **537.44** for **Java 8u5**.

This is the upstream version of WebKit used in the JavaFX implementation before any downstream modifications were made to it to allow it to work with JavaFX.

As new versions of Java 8 are released, the version of WebKit used in each version will change, but you should always be able to determine what is used by querying the User Agent String.

*Sample Code Output (on my machine)*

```
Java Version:   1.8.0_05-b13
JavaFX Version: 8.0.5-b13
OS:             Windows 7, amd64
User Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.44 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/537.44
```

*Sample Code*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewVersion extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        WebView web = new WebView();
        System.out.println(
                "Java Version:   " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")
        );
        System.out.println(
                "JavaFX Version: " + System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version")
        );
        System.out.println(
                "OS:             " + System.getProperty("os.name") + ", " 
                                   + System.getProperty("os.arch")
        );
        System.out.println(
                "User Agent:     " + web.getEngine().getUserAgent()
        );
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```