# What version of HTML and CSS does JavaFX support?

Tags: java, javafx

I've tried searching around but I haven't found anything :/ I just want to know what version of HTML and CSS JavaFX supports so that I can edit accordingly some of the web content I want to put into my application.

Comment: Can you clarify the question for CSS? Are you asking about the CSS applied to the JavaFX Scene graph, or about CSS supported by the `WebView` component (and applied to HTML displayed in the web view)?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I was wondering what version that WebView supports. As in, does it support up to HTML5 and CSS3?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214913/version-of-webkit-in-javafx-8-webview

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says CSS 2.1
see: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html
and: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations

Comment: Since this question is about CSS **and HTML** I guess it's about [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and not about the css used to style the scene graph.